# PSGSuite: Filtering Google accounts by creation date

Tags: powershell, google-api

I'm creating a script to get IDs of newly created Google accounts in a domain and sync them to a user in a database. The only problem is I cant seem to find a way (if there is one) to filter by created date. Is this possible, and if so how would I go about it?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Get-GSUser` function and pipe that to the `Where-Object` cmdlet to filter based on the `CreationTime` property. Here is an example:

```
Get-GSUser -Filter * | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-180)}
```

That gives you a list of all users that have been created in the last 180 days. Change the value supplied to the `.AddDays()` method with a different value to change your scope, e.g. `(Get-Date).AddDays(-365)` to get all users created in the last year.

Just to expand a bit on what we're doing there, you are saying show me all objects with a CreationTime property that is greater than `-gt` today's date minus 180 days `(Get-Date).AddDays(-180)`.